# Циклический сдвиг элементов матрицы

Tags: c++, c, массивы, циклы, матрицы

Нужно осуществить циклический сдвиг элементов квадратной матрицы размерности MxN вправо на k элементов таким образом: элементы 1-й строки сдвигаются в последний столбец сверху вниз, из него - в последнюю строку справа налево, из нее - в первый столбец снизу вверх, их него - в первую строку; для остальных элементов аналогично.

C/C++

Как это реализовать общим видом,чтобы работало для любой размерность ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define N 8

int main()
{
    int spiral[N][N], Step, cur[4 * (N - 1)], shift[4 * (N - 1)];
    int i, j, k, c, edge;
    //инициализация массива числами от 1 до 20
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Original array:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            spiral[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 1;
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d", i, j, spiral[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    //запрос количества шагов поворота
    printf("\nHow many steps to turn? Step = ");
    scanf("%d", &Step);

    for (k = 0; k < N / 2; k++) //слои
    {
        edge = N - 1 - k;
        //снять слой
        c = 0;

        for (j = k; j < edge; j++)
        {
            cur[c] = spiral[k][j];
            c++;
        }

        for (i = k; i < edge; i++)
        {
            cur[c] = spiral[i][edge];
            c++;
        }

        for (j = edge; j >= k; j--)
        {
            cur[c] = spiral[edge][j];
            c++;
        }

        for (i = edge - 1; i > k; i--)
        {
            cur[c] = spiral[i][k];
            c++;
        }

        //переставить
        for (i = 0; i < 4 * (N - 2 * k - 1); i++)
            shift[(i + Step) % (4 * (N - 2 * k - 1))] = cur[i];

        //одеть слой
        c = 0;

        for (j = k; j < edge; j++)
        {
            spiral[k][j] = shift[c];
            c++;
        }

        for (i = k; i < edge; i++)
        {
            spiral[i][edge] = shift[c];
            c++;
        }

        for (j = edge; j >= k; j--)
        {
            spiral[edge][j] = shift[c];
            c++;
        }

        for (i = edge - 1; i > k; i--)
        {
            spiral[i][k] = shift[c];
            c++;
        }
    }//for - переход на следующий слой

    //Результат
    printf("Result:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) printf("%6d", spiral[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Работает только для N константы ,как вводить это N с клаввиатуры.Если тупо выше объявить и ввести - ругается

Comment: Код? Где ваш код? Принесите код в студию!

Comment: Ну, а если строка, скажем, 5 символов, а столбец - 10, то как вы из столбца в строку переносить собираетесь?... И что такое у вас `k` - это как и куда сдвигать? Опишите схему подробнее, pls...

Comment: @Harry,Квадратная же матрица.

Comment: Знаете, что такое эллипс с точки зрения военного? Это окружность, вписанная в квадрат с разными сторонами. Я не понимаю, что такое (цитирую!) **квадратная матрица размерности MxN**. И все равно про `k` вы ничего не ответили.

Comment: @Harry,Прикрепил код

Comment: Вот пример квадратной матрицы - http://vpaste.net/NZzoE. Покажите, если не трудно, во что она должна в результате превратиться. И - как вариант - ну не делайте на месте, возьмите вторую матрицу и растасовывайте в нее...

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритмов циклического сдвига линейной последовательности - штук пять-шесть на выбор. А организовать пересчет линейных индексов в индексы соответствующего "кольца" в вашей матрице - труда не составит. Задача решена.

Более интересным (хотя, возможно, неоправданно более громоздким) С++ решением будет реализация собственного итератора, умеющего итерировать по "кольцу" матрицы, который затем можно просто использовать в `std::rotate`.